# Shiny plots are not being displayed

Tags: r, shiny

I discovered this problem while working on another app but below is a reproducible example straight from the shiny website.

Image based plots are not being displayed in my shiny app. The appear as if the browser cannot find the images. Other javascript based plots are working fine. This seems like a path issue but I am not sure what the problem is.

The app
Straight from the shiny website should work

```
library(shiny)

ui<-pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel('Iris k-means clustering'),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
      selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', names(iris),
                  selected=names(iris)[[2]]),
      numericInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 3,
                   min = 1, max = 9)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput('plot1')
    )
  )



server<-function(input, output, session) {

  # Combine the selected variables into a new data frame
  selectedData <- reactive({
    iris[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
  })

  clusters <- reactive({
    kmeans(selectedData(), input$clusters)
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    palette(c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#984EA3",
              "#FF7F00", "#FFFF33", "#A65628", "#F781BF", "#999999"))

    par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 0, 1))
    plot(selectedData(),
         col = clusters()$cluster,
         pch = 20, cex = 3)
    points(clusters()$centers, pch = 4, cex = 4, lwd = 4)
  })

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

session

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.1/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.1/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_CA.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_CA.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_CA.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_CA.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_CA.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.2.0.9001     RevoUtils_11.0.1     RevoUtilsMath_11.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.0        knitr_1.21        magrittr_1.5      devtools_1.13.6   xtable_1.8-3      R6_2.3.0          rlang_0.3.0.1    
 [8] stringr_1.3.1     httr_1.4.0        tools_3.5.1       xfun_0.4          git2r_0.23.0      withr_2.1.2       htmltools_0.3.6  
[15] yaml_2.2.0        digest_0.6.18     later_0.7.5.9001  base64enc_0.1-3   promises_1.0.1    rsconnect_0.8.12  curl_3.2         
[22] memoise_1.1.0     evaluate_0.12     mime_0.6          rmarkdown_1.11    stringi_1.2.4     compiler_3.5.1    jsonlite_1.6     
[29] httpuv_1.4.5.9002 Cairo_1.5-9
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a dev version of shiny installed. Have you tried removing it, installing a stable from CRAN and seeing if that fixes it?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the problem. There was something wrong with my R installation. It was not finding the paths of the images created by shiny. Uninstalling and re-installing R solved the issue. Didn't even need to update any packages or anything